# Laying out several plots in matplotlib + numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am pretty new to python and want to plot a dataset using a histogram and a heatmap below. However, I am a bit confused about

1. How to put a title above *both* plots and
2. How to insert some text into bots plots
3. How to reference the upper and the lower plot

For my first task I used the `title` instruction, which inserted a caption in between both plots instead of putting it above both plots

For my second task I used the `figtext` instruction. However, I could not see the text anywhere in the plot. I played a bit with the x, y and fontsize parameters without any success.

Here is my code:

```
def drawHeatmap(xDim, yDim, plot, threshold, verbose):
global heatmapList
stableCells = 0

print("\n[I] - Plotting Heatmaps ...")
for currentHeatmap in heatmapList:
    if -1 in heatmapList[currentHeatmap]:
        continue
    print("[I] - Plotting heatmap for PUF instance", currentHeatmap,"(",len(heatmapList[currentHeatmap])," values)")
    # Convert data to ndarray
    #floatMap = list(map(float, currentHeatmap[1]))
    myArray = np.array(heatmapList[currentHeatmap]).reshape(xDim,yDim)

    # Setup two plots per page
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)

    # Histogram        
    weights = np.ones_like(heatmapList[currentHeatmap]) / len(heatmapList[currentHeatmap])
    hist, bins = np.histogram(heatmapList[currentHeatmap], bins=50, weights=weights)
    width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
    center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
    ax[0].bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
    stableCells = calcPercentageStable(threshold, verbose)
    plt.figtext(100,100,"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", fontsize=40)


    heatmap = ax[1].pcolor(myArray, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, alpha=0.8, vmin=0, vmax=1)
    cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, shrink=0.8, aspect=10, fraction=.1,pad=.01)
    #cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=40) 
    for y in range(myArray.shape[0]):
        for x in range(myArray.shape[1]):
            plt.text(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, '%.2f' % myArray[y, x],
             horizontalalignment='center',
             verticalalignment='center',
             fontsize=(xDim/yDim)*5
             )

    #fig = plt.figure()
    fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
    fig.set_size_inches(60.5,55.5)
    plt.savefig(dataDirectory+"/"+currentHeatmap+".pdf", dpi=800, papertype="a3", format="pdf")
    #plt.title("Heatmap for PUF instance "+str(currentHeatmap[0][0])+" ("+str(numberOfMeasurements)+" measurements; "+str(sizeOfMeasurements)+" bytes)")
    if plot:
        plt.show()
    print("\t[I] - Done ...")
```

And here is my current output:[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this example will make things easier to understand.  Things to note are:

- Use `fig.suptitle` to add a title to the top of a figure.
- Use `ax[i].text(x, y, str)` to add text to an Axes object
- Each Axes object, `ax[i]` in your case, holds all the information about a single plot. Use them instead of calling `plt`, which only really works well with one subplot per figure or to modify all subplots at once.  For example, instead of calling `plt.figtext`, call `ax[0].text` to add text to the top plot.

Try following the example code below, or at least read through it to get a better idea how to use your `ax` list.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

histogram_data = np.random.rand(1000)
heatmap_data = np.random.rand(10, 100)

# Set up figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("These are my two plots")
top_ax = fig.add_subplot(211) #2 rows, 1 col, 1st plot
bot_ax = fig.add_subplot(212) #2 rows, 1 col, 2nd plot
# This is the same as doing 'fig, (top_ax, bot_ax) = plt.subplots(2)'

# Histogram
weights = np.ones_like(histogram_data) / histogram_data.shape[0]
hist, bins = np.histogram(histogram_data, bins=50, weights=weights)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2

# Use top_ax to modify anything with the histogram plot
top_ax.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
# ax.text(x, y, str). Make sure x,y are within your plot bounds ((0, 1), (0, .5))
top_ax.text(0.5, 0.5, "Here is text on the top plot", color='r')

# Heatmap
heatmap_params = {'cmap':plt.cm.Blues, 'alpha':0.8, 'vmin':0, 'vmax':1}

# Use bot_ax to modify anything with the heatmap plot
heatmap = bot_ax.pcolor(heatmap_data, **heatmap_params)
cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, shrink=0.8, aspect=10, fraction=.1,pad=.01)

# See how it looks
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Another question that came up: How would you add labels to the individual axes? For example, bot_ax.xlabel("test") doesnt work for me.

Comment: Use `set` and `get`. For example, `bot_ax.set_xlabel('label')` or `top_ax.get_yticklabels()`.